# Linear separability

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming

I have an assignment in linear programming and this question was asked:
given an input of two data sets $P_1,P_2$ containing points $(x,y)$, create a linear program that finds an equation of a line the separates between the two data sets.

Now I saw in Wikipedia the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_separability) about linear separability and I didn't understand what are the variables of $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n$ stand for, and why does their algorithm work. If anyone could clarify this for me it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

The general equation of a line in the plane is
$$
ax + by = c.
$$
(The equation $y = ax + b$ cannot handle vertical lines.) This line separates the plane into two parts: those satisfying $ax+by > c$, and those satisfying $ax+by < c$. Your two datasets are linearly separable if there exist $a,b,c$ such that all points in $P_1$ satisfy $ax+by > c$, and all points in $P_2$ satisfy $ax+by < c$. (If all points in $P_1$ satisfy $ax+by<c$ and all points in $P_2$ satisfy $ax+by>c$, then we can negate $a,b,c$ to get to the situation above.)

In order to find $a,b,c$ using linear programming, we need to replace the strict inequalities $>,<$ with non-strict inequalities $\ge,\le$. The idea is the for small enough $\epsilon>0$, the points in $P_1$ would actually satisfy $ax+by \geq c+\epsilon$, and the points in $P_2$ would satisfy $ax+by \leq c-\epsilon$. While we don't know $\epsilon$, if we multiply the two inequalities by $1/\epsilon$, we effectively make $\epsilon$ equal to $1$. Therefore we look for $a,b,c$ such that $ax+by \geq c+1$ for all points in $P_1$, and $ax+by \leq c-1$ for all points in $P_2$. This is a linear program, which can be solved using standard algorithms.